# Regex and PHP - how to match this string?

Tags: php, regex

I have this string:

```
First part of string. Second part one: Second part two; Third part: Fourth part 2014. Available online:
```

The string is made in this way:

- First part of string (dot)
- Second part one (colon)
- Second part two (semicolon)
- Third part (colon)
- Fourth part
- 4 digit number (dot)
- Available online (colon)

How it is possible to split this string in an array with as described, using regex?

Thank you.

Comment: "double dots" is called a colon

Comment: Oups, thanks a lot Scott, will change that immediately. Sorry for my english :)

Comment: And the 'dot' is called a period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
$array = preg_split('/\s*[:;.]\s*/', $str);
```

or even:

```
$array = preg_split('/\s*[:;.]\s*/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: Good idea, but what if I have some other semicolons in the first or second part...

Answer (score -1):

```
$string = "First part of string. Second part one: Second part two; Third part: Fourth part 2014. Available online:";
preg_match("/(.+?)\.(.+?):(.+?);(.+?):(.+?)(\d{4})\.(.+?):/",$string,$m);
print_r($m);
```

outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => First part of string. Second part one: Second part two; Third part: Fourth part 2014. Available online:
    [1] => First part of string
    [2] =>  Second part one
    [3] =>  Second part two
    [4] =>  Third part
    [5] =>  Fourth part 
    [6] => 2014
    [7] =>  Available online
)
```

Hope it'd help you.

Comment: Thank you, but this is to close to my example. I need to match anything in the part one, part two etc

Comment: @Milos - I believe it would match anything. What makes you think the opposite?

Answer (score -1):

Using:

```
([a-zA-Z ]+)\. ([a-zA-Z ]+): ([a-zA-Z ]+); ([a-zA-Z ]+): ([a-zA-Z ]+)([0-9]{4})\. ([a-zA-Z ]+):
```

Results in:

```
First part of string
Second part one
Second part two
Third part
Fourth part 
2014
Available online
```